# How can RELEASE SAVEPOINT return a result?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I have a function that needs to set some local variables for some SQL queries.  To do this, I wrap the call in a SAVEPOINT (since it may be in the middle of a transaction).  However, when I try to create and release a savepoint, I get an exception.  The code looks like this:

```java
        Savepoint savepoint = conn.setSavepoint();
        try {
          return findByNameTx(conn, names, threshold).stream();
        } finally {
          try {
            conn.releaseSavepoint(savepoint);
          } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.info("Ignoring rollback error", e);
          }
        }
```

However, when releasing the savepoint, the JDBC Postgres library complains about there being a result:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A result was returned when none was expected.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.execSQLUpdate(PgConnection.java:594)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.releaseSavepoint(PgConnection.java:1812)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.releaseSavepoint(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at ...CompanyDao.findByNameTx(CompanyDao.java:389)
```

The code doesn't save what was returned, so I am at a loss as to what could be coming back.   What is the correct way to release the savepoint?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. Which version of PostgreSQL, Java, and the JDBC driver?

Comment: 42.6.0 is the JDBC library, with PostgreSQL 14.7, And Java 20.  Also using Hikari.

Comment: That should work just fine, I'd say. You'll have to trace through the JDBC code with a debugger, unless you provide a *complete* self-contained reproducer that allows us to reproduce what you see. Also, you forgot to say what `findByNameTx` does, and that might be quite relevant.